# When sharing a blog link on social media the link thumbnail and title is not coming there in Gatsby even we've all the required meta tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a blogs page where I have separate pages of every blog and I want to show the thumbnail & title of every blog when sharing the link those data are dynamically coming.

Here is my code, how I'm doing it currently

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nickelfox Technologies" />

<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta property="og:url" content="https://nickelfox.com/" />

<meta property="og:title" content={blogData.title} />

<meta property="og:description" content={blogData.excerpt} />

<meta property="og:image" content={blogImage} />
```

Comment: The Facebook scraper does not care for any client-side JavaScript. The initial HTML code your system delivers when the URL is requested, needs to contain the proper meta data already.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you will get your answer from this

https://www.emgoto.com/gatsby-metatags/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).